# Cyrus' Adventure (Part 7)

Tags: cipher

The wall opened. Cyrus and T.E.D. got out of the room. Suddenly, the passageway started collapsing! Cyrus was terrified. T.E.D. grabbed Cyrus and quickly rolled out of the passageway. They got into another small room. Cyrus was relieved, as he thought he was going to die. "Thank you," he said as he hugged the robot. However, the robot seemed to be a bit confused.

They walked out of the room, and went into a long, hollow tunnel. It was very dark, so the robot turned on its lighting device. Surprisingly, the tunnel wasn't that long as they expected. They walked out of the tunnel and walked into a damp passageway. There were three little lines of words on the wall:

---

The first one:

> TAP ME!

The second one:

> TAP ME!

The third one:

> TAP ME!

Cyrus was confused. He asked T.E.D. which one he should press. T.E.D. answered:

> Thcoaeonp·ne·sd·te··5

What should Cyrus do?

---

Hint:

> Spartan people

Comment: It is actually a scytale cipher. 5 indicates that you should turn 5 times of the band.

Comment: Qbrf nalbar trg gur uvag?

Comment: Sorry for late answering. Scytale is used by ancient roman generals to convey messages, especially Spartan people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cyrus should:

> Tap·the·second·one··

Method:

> Skip 4... not sure what the hint implies, or what the 5 was for.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your method. Could you expand on it please?

Comment: Since both of you are correct, I'll give it to LeppyR64, who answered first.

Answer (score 6):

> I guessed the "5" is the clue to tell us that we have to put the letters in the right order.
>  So if we take each 5 letters **Thcoaeonp·ne·sd·te··** become **Tap·the·second·one··**
>  So Cyrus have to tap the second line. 
>  I don't get the hint.